# Azure AD B2C user login redirect URI not recognized

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing a user login using Azure AD B2C. I've created an App Registration in my B2C tenant and added http://localhost:3000 as the redirect URI. Now I've also implemented it in my React app using the MSAL React library. For some weird reason I'm getting the error that the client using "xxx id" does not have http://localhost:3000 set as a redirect URI. This must be something stupid and small, but I'm just not seeing it.

This is the error I'm getting:
`AADB2C90006: The redirect URI 'http://localhost:3000' provided in the request is not registered for the client id 'xxx'.`

Now I'm using the provided client ID to search my Azure, I'm finding the App Registration, and I see the following:
[image]

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was impatient. Just took about ten minutes.